# RFC822 to date format using asp

Tags: datetime, asp-classic, date-format, rfc822

I try converting RFC822 date format (from rss) into a standard date/time format
using asp3.

Thanks

Comment: *What* have you tried?  What errors are you getting?  Samples & logs, please.

Comment: I tried cDate(temp) or year(temp)&"/"&month(temp)&"/"&day(temp)

Answer (score 1):

Nice solution - the minutes don't always go into double figures though - you'll need to pad those out if minutes are just one digit (I think CDate removes that zero)

eg.

```
dim theminutes
```

...

```
tempDate  = cdate(tempDate) 

if Len(Minute(toReturn))=1 then
    theminutes = "0" & Minute(toReturn) 
else                            
    theminutes = Minute(toReturn) 
end if
RFC822_to_date  = day(tempDate )&"-"&month(tempDate )&"-"&year(tempDate )&" "&hour(tempDate )&":"&theminutes&":00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code of this Classic ASP [RSS reader](http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/07/01/asp-vbscript-rss-readerwriter-class/).

There are some funky functions involving the use of JScript, which look like they will work for you.

It looks like you need the VBScript functions `parseDate` and `newDate`, and the two JScript functions.

Comment: this using CDATE - but for some reason i can't do cdate on my string

private function formatDate(aDate)
  d = cDate(aDate)
  formatDate = toUTC(year(d), month(d) - 1, day(d), hour(d), minute(d), second(d))
 end function

Answer (score 0):

```
function RFC822_to_date (orginalDate )
 tempDate = trim(right(orginalDate ,(len(orginalDate )-instr(orginalDate,","))))
 tempDate  = left(tempDate ,(len(tempDate)-5))
 tempDate  = cdate(tempDate )
 RFC822_to_date  = day(tempDate )&"-"&month(tempDate )&"-"&year(tempDate )&" "&hour(tempDate )&":"&minute(tempDate )&":00"
end function
```